# UI freezes when I create a View using find() and open it in modal window

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a TableView in MainView and I continuously adding a lot of data to it (>2-10 rows per second).
Also I have an button with below action:

```
button.action {
   val window = find<AnotherView>("param" to mainViewModel.param)
   window.openModal(modality = Modality.WINDOW_MODAL, escapeClosesWindow = false)
}
```

UI (tableView in particular) freezes on 1-1.5 seconds when I'm clicking on the button while the data adding in tableView. If I close AnotherView and again click on the button new window is opening **almost** without tableView freezing.

Is anybody know, how to fix this freezing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are fetching the data on the UI thread. You need to fetch the data in a background thread and only update the table items when you have the data available. An easy way to do this is run use `runAsync { fetchData() }` ui { table.items = it }`, or even use the`table. If this doesn't resolve the issue you need to post the code in `AnotherView` so we can see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I already asynchronously fetch data. It seems like UI thread needs too much time for painting the `AnotherView` in method `openModal()`, so it blocks `tableView` repainting when I add fetched data using `table.itemProperty()`

Comment: Then you need to post a complete runnable sample that exhibits this behavior. We can't debug a View when all you've given us is the name :)